# Foreach help in smarty

Tags: php, foreach, smarty

I am new to smarty and need help with the foreach in it. I have a array $results that has two keys one is times which can have values from one to ten and another key called home which can have some value in it. What I am trying to do is find the mod with value two and then print the corresponding home value. Can someone please help me with this. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: What have you tried? You should post some sample code, especially the PHP that contains this data (even if it's just sample data) and the smarty code you have tried and doesn't work.

Comment: what is 'find the mod'?

Answer (score 0):

What do you not understand from http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.section.tpl